# While loop not exiting with "break"

Tags: python, list, while-loop, break

I am making a class that reads a large csv file and and converts part of that data into a line graph. But came across this little issue, whenever I run this method, for some reason, the `break` statement does not work and the loop restarts even when the input is correct.

```
def get_user_country(self):
    while True:
        user_country = input("Enter the country to retrieve data from: ").lower()
        if user_country in self.country_list:
            print("Country exists")
            break
        elif user_country not in self.country_list:
            print("That country isn´t in availible")
            view_data = input("Do you wish to see the availible countries? (y/n):").lower()
            if view_data == "y":
                for index, country in enumerate(self.country_list):
                    print(index, country)

    return user_country
```

Comment: What do you input, and what happens?

Comment: Basically, I input a country name, if that country is in the list "self.countries_list" the loop should break, but it doesn´t, it just starts again.

Comment: Print out `user_country` and `self.country_list` to see the problem. Also, you don't need to write `if X: ... else if not X: ...`. You just write `if X: ... else: ...`

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mre] (because we all know `break` generally does work).

Comment: Your code works fine, as shown, removing the class elements. So, your bug is in the code you haven't shown. Please add that code. Guessing that `self.country_list` is populated incorrectly, e.g. contains 'France' instead of 'france'.